# Drawing artifacts in Mac 10.9

Tags: xcode, macos

I opened a project today and ran it to find odd drawing issues everywhere.  Images aren't being rendered, cell aren't drawing properly, text isn't being rendered, black lines appear across alternating rows in table views, segmented controls are missing text, and more.

I ran this code without any other changes just a few days ago.  I also distributed binaries that worked and still work. Despite this, I assumed it was something I had changed in the code so I checked out several commits from weeks and even a month back.  The problem still shows up.  I can run any of the already built (and archived) binaries, but anything new I build has this issue.

I don't see errors reported in the Console.  No exceptions or breaks triggering.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Mac 10.9 Xcode 5.0.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own solution: 10.9 added colorWithWhite:alpha: and colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: to NSColor which conflict with the ones I added years ago to bring certain code in common with iOS.

Now have to find the best way to support these on 10.7 and 10.8.